# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open_now' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Using google places api i'm trying to check if a search result is currently open. If so i want to display a "still open" text at the infowindow of the marker. Here is the code sample:

```
 // Get the place details. Show the information in an info window,
// anchored on the marker for the result that the user selected.
function showInfoWindow() {
  var marker = this;
  places.getDetails({ placeId: marker.placeResult.place_id }, function(
    place,
    status
    ) {
    if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      return;
    }
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    buildIWContent(place);
  });
}
function buildIWContent(place) {
if (place.opening_hours.open_now) {
    var openNow = place.opening_hours.open_now;
    if (openNow === true) {
      document.getElementById("iw-now-row").style.display = "";
      document.getElementById("iw-now").innerHTML = "still open";
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("iw-now-row").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

This code results to the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open_now' of undefined" on my console, although I still get the Information that I want. Does anybody know what is wrong here?

**EDIT**: Following the comment from geocodezip, I created a simple [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SharPei/qL21wrfn/). By clicking on the marker, although the information is being displayed correctly, the console gives back the error message.

Comment: It seems that there is no information about opening_hours for some place. I think it is not necessary information for all place, so this parameter can be undefined sometimes. Try to check this

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.